# How to configure gitlab-ci for Laravel + Nuxt + Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, nuxt.js, gitlab-ci

I'm building a project based on this [boilerplate](https://github.com/nevadskiy/laravel-nuxt-docker) but cannot figure out how to set up GitLab CI/CD for it. I have a DigitalOcean server running Ubuntu 20.4 and followed this [tutorial](https://digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-7-%E2%80%94-validating-the-deployment) for basic config.

Here is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - publish
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

api:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - build
  image: registry.gitlab.com/my-gitlab-user/my-gitlab-project-name/api:latest
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-api
    policy: pull-push
    paths:
      - api/vendor/
  script:
    - time composer install -d api --no-interaction --ansi
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    expire_in: 2 hour
    paths:
      - api/vendor/
  only:
    - dev
    - master

client:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - build
  image: registry.gitlab.com/my-gitlab-user/my-gitlab-project-name/client:latest
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-client
    policy: pull-push
    paths:
      - client/node_modules/
  script:
    - time yarn --cwd client install
    - node -v
    - npm -v
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    expire_in: 2 hour
    paths:
      - client/node_modules/
  only:
    - dev
    - master

publish:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  dependencies:
    - api
    - client
  tags:
    - publish
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST docker/client
    - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST docker/api
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

dev:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deploy
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - cat $API_ENV > .env
    - cat docker-compose.dev.yml > docker-compose.yml
    - scp -pr -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no docker-compose.yml $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:$SERVER_PATH
    - scp -pr -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no .env $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:$SERVER_PATH/api
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP
      "
      cd $SERVER_PATH &&
      docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY &&
      docker pull $TAG_COMMIT &&
      docker container rm -f my-app || true &&
      docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT
      "
    - exit 0
  environment:
    name: production
    url: $HOST
  only:
    - dev
  when: manual
```

The 3 stage is 100% incorrect, but I do not understand how deploy should be configured. If you check the [boilerplate](https://github.com/nevadskiy/laravel-nuxt-docker) you will see that everything in separate folders. Should I scp docker folder to my server?

Comment: It seems that you've just missed defining the `admin` job, `publish job: undefined dependency: admin`

Comment: Hi Miguel. Thanks for your comment. I split admin and client into 2 separate nuxt frontend apps, but for the sake of simplification I removed admin from my question because it is basically the same as client. I corrected my question and removed admin from dependencies at publish stage and added details to my initial question.